# Actualizar div sin recargar pagina con jQuery

Tags: jquery

estoy intentando actualizar un div sin recargar la página, para ello lo hago con jQuery, y me va bien, pero hay un pequeño error y es que al actualizar el div, las funciones no se ejecutan. Me explico, yo tengo un div donde una serie de actividades que el usuario puede eliminar, y en la funcion puse que al ser exitoso, me recargue el div, de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#divacargar").load("paginaexterna.php");
```

La pagina externa contiene esto.

```
      <p id="title"><b>Educaplay</b><i class="fa fa-close close_popup_educaplay"></i></p>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <?php include('educaplay.php') ?>
  </div>
  <div class="div_eliminacion">
    <svg id="cubo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70 76">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1{fill:#ed1c24;}
          .cls-1-tapa{fill:#ed1c24;}
          .cls-2{fill:#c1272d;}
        </style>
      </defs>
      <rect class="cls-1" y="16" width="70" height="60" rx="12" ry="12"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="49" y="26" width="10" height="40" rx="2.5" ry="2.5"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="29" y="26" width="10" height="40" rx="2.5" ry="2.5"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="9" y="26" width="10" height="40" rx="2.5" ry="2.5"/>
      <path class="cls-1-tapa" d="M80,30H60V27.1A3.12,3.12,0,0,0,56.9,24H43.1A3.12,3.12,0,0,0,40,27.1V30H20a5,5,0,0,0,0,10H80a5,5,0,0,0,0-10Z" transform="translate(-15 -24)"/>
    </svg>
    <form method="POST" id="form_identificador"><textarea style="display: none;" id="identificador" name="identidad"></textarea></form>
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.g-t-e.260mb.net/profesorado/imagenes/eliminar_todo_act.png" id="eliminar_todo_educaplay" title="Elimimar todas las actividades" alt="Eliminar todo">
```

Este div tiene varias funciones como el fa-close para salir del propio div pero al recargar el div autoomáticamente con .load() no funciona, las funciones ya no se ejecutan, y no sé porque.

¿Alguien sabe porque? Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Conviene que seas lo más claro posible. ¿De qué funciones hablas? No veo funciones por ningún lado.

Comment: No queda claro que es lo que no se ejecuta